# Check if the current path in gohugo matches a pattern with regex

Tags: regex, hugo

I'm trying to check if the current url is of the format : `http://localhost:1313/categories/.../` so matching routes under `categories` route, using regular expression.

I tried this:

```
{{if (eq .Permalink (`categories/*/` | absURL))}}
    <h4 class="mb-3 text-dark font-weight-bold">
        Showing posts with <mark>{{.Title}}</mark> category
    </h4>
{{else}} # means :{{if (eq .Permalink (`tags/*/` | absURL))}}
    <h4 class="mb-3 text-dark font-weight-bold">
       Showing posts with <mark>{{.Title}}</mark> tag
    </h4>
{{end}}
```

Any help or advice will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: If you don't get a good answer here, there is a hugo-specific forum at https://discourse.gohugo.io/.

Comment: Yeah, thank you man !